# While booting and shutdown Ubuntu shows the process it is executing in black screen. Graphical page is not getting display

Tags: boot

While booting and shutdown Ubuntu shows the process it is executing in black screen. Graphical page is not getting display. It will take 4 minutes to boot and 1 minute to shutdown. My current ubuntu is 19.04

Answer (score 0):

Solution is u have to edit grub program

cat /etc/default/grub

Change the below line

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="drm.debug=0xe quiet splash"

and reboot